# FineUploaderS3: socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period

Tags: fine-uploader

We are using FineUploader 5.4.1's jQuery uploader. Periodically, our uploads to AWS S3 are failing. It's working consistently from one of our office locations and failing from the other.

**Request:**

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1129759
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Host:s3.amazonaws.com
Origin:
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/47.0.2526.73 Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

virginia/original/b71bb640-c771-44d9-9d28-44a075197bc3.png
------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

image/png
------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"

200
------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"

public-read
------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-meta-qqparentuuid"

3d343555-7821-43d3-a954-aba2ce17f597
------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-meta-qqparentsize"

983029
------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-meta-qquuid"

b71bb640-c771-44d9-9d28-44a075197bc3
------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-meta-qqfilename"

missing%20(o).png
------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"

AKIAIVACH6FJDZWZ5LYA
------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"

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
------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

J7XwHe5kmIVXznw+8cIiGwiyLbE=
------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundarySNlCNy1xiPquuzCl--

**Response:**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>RequestTimeout</Code><Message>Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.</Message><RequestId>C7E8E596E8FF701A</RequestId><HostId>aIePbPl+NPEr3/6LZkV9KlFzVpPTapnROfoNgI/DN+/t1zrttudxSADiPcCdwVnBq15BDKeodwY=</HostId></Error>`

On the same network, AWS CLI managed to upload the same file successfully multiple times.

Our FineUploader settings:

```
{
    uploaderType: 'basic',
    maxConnections: 3,
    request: {
        endpoint: <OUR BUCKET>,
        accessKey: <OUR UPLOAD KEY>
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: <OUR UPLOAD SIGNATURE ENDPOINT>
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: <OUR UPLOAD SUCCESS ENDPOINT>,
        params: {
            param1: "Hello",
            param2: "World"
        }
    },
    iframeSupport: {
        localBlankPagePath: <HTML FILE URL>
    },
    retry: {
        showButton: true
    },
    chunking: {
        enabled: true
    },
    resume: {
        enabled: true
    },
    validation: {
        sizeLimit: 150000000
    },
    messages: {
        typeError: '{file} has an invalid extension. Valid      extension(s):   {extensions}.'
    }
};
```

Tried with and without chunking.

Comment: did you find out what is the issue and how we can solve it i am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a pretty clear-cut occasional network issue at one of your offices. You can read more about potential causes at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/281. That case suggests that the Content-Length, which is set by the browser and not Fine Uploader, is larger than the actual number of bytes sent. This to me suggests that a network issue is preventing all bytes from being sent in some cases.

Comment: Hi Ray, we have a 10 Mbps leased line so the upload speeds have been fairly good all day. In fact, I checked the upload speed online right after one of the failures and it was quite high. Is there any other reason this could happen?

Comment: Possible. Behind a proxy, the same file gets uploaded consistently without issues!

Could you please recommend a way to handle this?

Comment: If a proxy fixes the issue, perhaps some firewall or other network appliance on your network is causing problems with requests from time to time. Next step is to survey your network to figure out what is causing the issue. Fine Uploader will auto-retry anyway.